# Scrollable table inside div with div having limited maximum height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an absolute positioned div, inside a table is positioned (centered).
This table can have 5 rows or 15 rows or more.
I would like my div (and the table/rows) to be displayed  up to a maximum height of X. If that height is reached, the div should take this max  height and the table/rows should show a scroll bar, to scroll the table inside the div.

How would i be able to achieve this ?

Comment: use `max-height :Xpx; overfloy-y : scroll;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a combination of `max-height` on the container and `overflow-y: auto` on the table, it's fairly straightforward:

```css
.special-table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.special-table table {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 0 auto; /* centers the table */
}
```

```html
<h1>When Everything Fits</h1>
<div class="special-table">
  <table>
    <tr><th>Foo</th><td>Bar</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Foo</th><td>Bar</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Foo</th><td>Bar</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<h1>When the Table Overflows</h1>
<div class="special-table">
  <table>
    <tr><th>Foo</th><td>Bar</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Foo</th><td>Bar</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Foo</th><td>Bar</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Foo</th><td>Bar</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Foo</th><td>Bar</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Foo</th><td>Bar</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Foo</th><td>Bar</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Foo</th><td>Bar</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Foo</th><td>Bar</td></tr>
    <tr><th>Foo</th><td>Bar</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how give auto focus on specific rows ?
I.e. i have many rows and i want a certain row (using jquery.data) to always be the "focus" of the element, i.e. always at the exact "middle" of the wraping div ?

Comment: The would involve some JavaScript. If you're trying to scroll to a certain row when the page loads or some other event happens, that's certainly doable. I'm not sure what you mean by "always" at the exact middle, since that would seem to preclude the table from scrolling.

Answer (score -1):

```
tbl{
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
  position: absolute;
}
```